# Robot Rendezvous Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, conditional-statements

I am having an issue getting started with the code.

The problem's description reads:

Robot Rendezvous: 
Imagine a room in which there are n designated “locations”, numbered 1 to n. Two robots, R2 and D2, are placed into the room, possibly at different locations. The robots are programmed so that, whenever a gong is sounded, they simultaneously move to a specified “next” location, according to a given “map”. A map indicates, for each location, which location should be visited next. Thus, a map can be viewed as a function f such that, for each integer i satisfying 1 ≤ i ≤ n, if a robot is at location i, then, upon hearing a gong, it will move to location f(i).

Develop a program that, given as input the number of locations in the room, the initial locations of R2 and D2, and the (common) map that they have been programmed to follow, determines whether the two robots will ever meet (i.e., be at the same location at the same time), and, if so, the location and time (i.e., after how many gong soundings) of their first meeting. If the robots will never meet, that fact should be reported by the program.

Hint: Developing a program that simulates the movements of the two robots is a good ap- proach. However, a program that performs such a simulation, stopping only when the robots meet, is not a correct solution, because it gets trapped in an infinite loop in the case that the robots never meet.

Input 
The input is as follows: The first line contains a positive integer n indicating the number of locations in the room. (You may assume that n ≤ 100.) The second line contains two positive integers (in the range 1 to n) that indicate the initial locations of R2 and D2, respectively. The third line contains a sequence of n positive integers, each in the range 1 to n, representing the map. For each i satisfying 1 ≤ i ≤ n, the i-th number in the sequence indicates the location that is to be visited immediately after location i. (Viewing the map as a function f, the i-th number in the sequence gives the value f(i).)

Output 
The output should include a line that says either “Robots never meet” or “Robots meet at location p after t moves”, where p and t are filled in correctly. In particular, p and t should describe the location and time (i.e., number of moves preceding) the robots’ first meeting.

Sample Input:

10

3 4

5 6 8 7 8 1 9 5 4 6

10

3 2

5 6 8 7 8 1 9 5 4 6

10

3 6

5 6 8 7 8 1 9 5 4 6

15

2 10

2 4 7 5 3 4 5 9 11 13 8 6 3 11 14

14

1 12

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 10 11 12 13 2 3

Corresponding output:

Robots never meet.

Robots never meet.

Robots meet at location 5 after 2 moves.

Robots never meet.

Robots meet at location 8 after 8 moves

The method I have at the moment is:

```
public static String robotsMeet(int R2, int D2, int mapSize, int[] map){

    for (int i = map[0]; i < map.length; i++){
            R2 *= map[i];
            D2 *= map[i];
            if (R2 == D2){
                return "Robots meet at location " + map[i] + " after "+ i + " moves.";
            }
    }

    return "Robots never meet.";

}
```

It would be of great help if I could be lead in the right direction or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As a step in the right direction, I think the "trick" is to understand that the location is the offset into the array, and that at each step it is necessary to look into the array and update. As to the ultimate terminating condition, that is something that needs to be considered. For demonstration purposes, I assumed that if they didn't meet in 200,000 steps, they wouldn't, but that is not necessary correct. So, I'd look at that question.

Also, I based this answer on the tag of 'arrays'. I suspect the real solution to this question is actually using a graph.

Leaving aside how to load the data from a file, I used an `Input` class that has the basic data (getters/setters omitted). The one "trick" I used is that in creating the sequence array, I adjusted it so that `[0]` was bogus. Otherwise, one would need to deal with adding/subtracting from the 1 based inputs in the file.

```
class Input
{
    int size = 0;
    int r2Start = 0;
    int d2Start = 0;
    Integer[] sequence = new Integer[0]; 

    ...

    // takes the integers and creates the array
    // assumes that the size is set first, and that there are
    // are an equal number of entries for the size of the room
    // NOTE: offsets the array by 1 to avoid needing to adjust lookups elsewhere
    public Input addSequence(int ... inpSeq)
    {
        if (inpSeq.length != size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("elements and size not equal: "
                    + inpSeq.length + " vs. size of " + size);
        }

        if (sequence.length != size + 1) {
            sequence = new Integer[size + 1];
        }

        int loc = 1;
        for (int i : inpSeq) {
            sequence[loc++] = i;
        }
        return this;
    }
 }
```

From this starting point, the magic is in the processing based upon this input. Again, a better terminating condition should probably be selected. The `debugLoc` method (not shown) just takes a format and a Object... input, and outputs it via `System.out.printf(...)`.

```
public static Result process(Input inp)
{
    Result result = new Result();
    // we have offset the sequence so that [0] is bogus
    // this avoid adding +1 everywhere, as arrays are 0-based,
    // but the input is 1 based; this difference is a silly trick
    // and not really a good example. Another way to have handled
    // this situation would be to subtract one on the initial load,
    // but that makes some debugging more difficult
    Integer[] seq = inp.getSequence(); 

    // where r2 is located at the beginning depends upon the location
    // in the array; in essence, the beginning # is the entry in the
    // array
    int r2Loc = seq[inp.getR2Start()];

    // same thing for d2
    int d2Loc = seq[inp.getD2Start()];

    // the total number of iterations
    // NOTE: a better terminating condition should be developed
    int cntr = 0; 

    while (! result.isMet() && cntr < 200000) {
        debugLoc("Step %d: r2: %d, d2: %d\n",
                cntr + 1, r2Loc, d2Loc);

        // see if we are at the same spot
        if (r2Loc == d2Loc) {
            result.setMet(true).setStep(cntr + 1).setLoc(r2Loc);
            break;
        }


        // get the location where going; it is the offset
        // given in the sequence from the current loc
        r2Loc = seq[r2Loc];
        d2Loc = seq[d2Loc];

        debugLoc("r2 moving to %d; d2 moving to %d\n",
                r2Loc, d2Loc);

        ++cntr;
    } //while

    return result;
}
```

The `Result` class just tracks the results. Getters/setters omitted:

```
private static class Result
{
    boolean met = false;
    int step = -1;
    int loc = -1;

   ...
}
```

Based upon the sample input data, the following output was obtained:

> Robots never meet
>   Robots never meet
>   Robots meet at location 5 after 2 moves
>   Robots never meet
>   Robots meet at location 8 after 8 moves

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to get into specific code details, since this really a question about *strategies we can use* to find a solution. So let's dive right in:

**Always look at sample data for clues**

Let's peek at the first data set

```
10

3 4

5 6 8 7 8 1 9 5 4 6
```

So we have ten locations, and each of these locations has only one, one-way route to another location. Already from this, we know something for certain: Even in the longest possible route, such as 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1, after ten locations the robot will start retracing its steps.

**Can we find the boundaries of the problem?**

Two of anything in orbits or cycles of different frequencies (or the same frequency) will create a beat pattern. This beat pattern will evolve through all its possible permutations over the product of the two frequencies. So the maximum number of cycles we'd ever need to simulate in this case (of ten locations) is 10*10, or 100. I don't think you're expected to know this, but it'd massively reduce KevinO's simulation answer to know how many steps to simulate in this way.

**Do we need to model or re-model the data?**

Here's where we get our biggest gains. Let's reconstruct the map, briefly, and find out where a robot would go if it started in each consecutive room:

```
1 5 8 5 (8 5 8 5 ...)
2 6 1 5 8 5 (8 5 ...)
3 8 5 8 (5 8 5 ...)
4 7 9 4 (7 9 4 ...)
5 8 5 (8 5 ...)
6 1 5 8 5 (8 5 ...)
7 9 4 7 (9 4 ...)
8 5 8 (5 8 ...)
9 4 7 9 (4 7 ...)
10 6 1 5 8 5 (8 5 ...)
```

Notice anything? I did:

```
1 5 8 5 (8 5 8 5 ...)
2 6 1 5 8 5 (8 5 ...)
3 8 5 8 (5 8 5 ...)
5 8 5 (8 5 ...)
6 1 5 8 5 (8 5 ...)
8 5 8 (5 8 ...)
10 6 1 5 8 5 (8 5 ...)
----------------------
4 7 9 4 (7 9 4 ...)
7 9 4 7 (9 4 ...)
9 4 7 9 (4 7 ...)
```

In this example, *there are two completely separate tracks*. They don't ever touch. So if you placed a robot at 3, it would get caught in the 8-5 loop; if you placed the other at 4, it would get caught in the 7-9-4 loop, and nary would the two touch. I strongly suspect that this is the real objective of the exercise.

So taking a step back, the way the exercise describes the map of arrows from room to room strongly resembles a *directed graph*. If they describe a data structure you should almost certainly be building it and looking at whether its strengths can be used to collapse the hard problem into simple ones. In this case, you build two graphs, realize that the robots start in different graphs, and reply "Robots never meet.".

From there, the graph representation is fairly efficient to simulate on, keeping in mind you know you never have to exceed n*n steps, where n is the total number of rooms *in the graph the robots are both in*.